# How to limit a google calendar xml / rss feed by date range (not working!!)

Tags: google-calendar-api

For the life of me I cannot get my google calendar xml feed to only display events within a certain date range.  I know that start-min and start-max are supposed to limit the output (according to these posts:

(links to posts deleted because I am a newbie and can only post one hyperlink argh)

BUT I CAN'T GET IT TO WORK.  It keeps showing lot of things outside the range.

I created a sample calendar and made it public.  It is some events the first week of april.  Can anyone show me how to construct a request that only returns those three events from the first week in april?

I'll GLADLY and GRATEFULLY paypal $10 to anyone who helps me break through on this.

Here is the calendar's public feed:

http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/66m31c36sj9u5k8kekrvt2lpr8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic

Answer (score 9):

This link should limit it to events from the 1st of April to the 7th of April using the start-min and start-max options you mention

http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/66m31c36sj9u5k8kekrvt2lpr8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?start-min=2010-04-01T00:00:00&start-max=2010-04-07T23:59:59

If this helps and you really want to paypal someone $10, please send it to the SPCA - http://rnzspca.org.nz/ :)

Comment: even though 3 years old...upvoted due to suggesting donations to a good cause!